# Update database from same table on like matches + reference column

Tags: sql

I have a database where I would like to update rows in column B based upon data from like matches in column A and exact matches in column C.

Column A is a SKU. Column C is a pricing category (A - retail, B - small warehouse, c- big warehouse). Row 1, 7 and 10 are all the same SKU in the same pricing category (A) and I need the pricing data from Column B to match. Row 1 is the correct pricing data which I want to copy to rows 7 and 10.

The reason Rows 1, 7 and 10 are the same SKU is our ERP utilizes options within the X1234F and X1234P configurations. The main pricing data will always come from SKUs without the X/F/P configuration options.

Sample:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2000 | A |
| 1234 | 1900 | B |
| 1234 | 1800 | C |
| 2355 | 1000 | A |
| 2355 | 900 | B |
| 2355 | 800 | C |
| X1234F | 1900 | A |
| X1234F | 1800 | B |
| X1234F | 1700 | C |
| X1234P | 1900 | A |
| X1234P | 1800 | B |
| X1234P | 1700 | C |
| X2355F | 900 | A |
| X2355F | 800 | B |
| X2355F | 700 | C |
| X2355P | 900 | A |
| X2355P | 800 | B |
| X2355P | 700 | C |

The data from Column B rows 1-3 should update rows 7-12 and rows 4-6 should update 13-18

Comment: Whatr RDBMS are you using, and when you say "creating secondary table" do you mean you want a `CREATE TABLE` statement, or do you just want a derived-table?

Comment: Just edited the post and removed that comment. In order to post originally it asked me what I tried.  I tried creating a second table where I stripped the X/F/P to match and pull the data from.

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly

Comment: Column A is a SKU.  Column C is a pricing category (A - retail, B - small warehouse, c- big warehouse).  Row 1, 7 and 10 are all the same SKU in the same pricing category and I need the pricing data from Column B to match.  Row 1 is the correct pricing data which I want to copy to rows 7 and 10).

Comment: please update your question directly and explain why rows 1,7,10 are all the same SKU, ie what is the rule to know this ? And how do you know that row 1 is the right pricing data ?

Comment: Our ERP utilizes options within the X1234F and X1234P configurations.  The main pricing data will come from SKUs without the X/F/P configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_table AS u
   SET "Column B" = ref."Column B"
  FROM my_table AS ref
 WHERE ref."Column A" ~ ^\d*$'  -- the ref."Column A" has only digits
   AND u."Column A" ~ '^\D+' || ref."Column A" || \D+$'  -- the u."Column A" is like the ref."Column A" with one or more non-digit character before and after
   AND u."Column C" = ref."Column C"
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect is this?

Comment: This is postgres with regular expression language. This should be working also with other rdbs with no or few adaptation